# verify sha1sum and print directory & filename of corrupt files

Tags: find, hashsum, sha1sum

I have a series of directories with sha1sums and md5sums files in.  The format of these files is the usual `hash space space filename`, with one hash/file per line.  I want to verify the files and print out the path as well as the filename of corrupt files.

```
find . -name SHA1SUMS -execdir echo "$PWD" sha1sum --quiet --check SHA1SUMS \; > logfile
```

(modified from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1013468/recursively-md5-files-compared-to-stored-md5-file)) gives

```
./path1/SHA1SUMS
sda2.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa: FAILED
blkdev.list: FAILED
Info-dmi.txt: FAILED
./path2/SHA1SUMS
```

Whereas I am looking more for a

```
./path1/sda2.ntfs-ptcl-img.gz.aa: FAILED
./path1/blkdev.list: FAILED
./path2/file: FAILED
```

type of output.

Comment: Minor point: your sample output seems to come from `find . -name SHA1SUMS -print -execdir 2>/dev/null sha1sum --quiet --check {} \;` (and not from the shown command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bsh
find . -name SHA1SUMS -exec sh -c '
  cd "${1%/*}" &&
  sha1sum --check --quiet "${1##*/}" 2>/dev/null |
    while IFS= read -r file
    do
      printf "%s\n" "${1%/*}/$file"
    done' sh {} \;
```

Its output should match the sample shown in your question and it should work with arbitrary paths.

Alternatively, using `awk` instead of shell features for prepending `SHA1SUMS`'s relative path to each file name:

```bsh
find . -name SHA1SUMS -exec sh -c '
  cd "${1%/*}" &&
  sha1sum --check --quiet "${1##*/}" 2>/dev/null |
    awk -v pre="${1%/*}" "{ print pre \"/\" \$0 }"' sh {} \;
```

Note that, depending on its implementation, `sha1sum` may print altered file names. Specifically, GNU `*sum` utilities escape some characters<sup>1</sup> and, when in check mode, prepend a `\` to file names that need escaping, making the path obtained concatenating the relative path of your `SHA1SUMS` file and a file name printed by `sha1sum` unsuitable for reuse.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/md5sum-invocation.html) (`sha1sum`'s manual refers to that of `md5sum`) says, generically, "each problematic character".</sub>

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
here=$(pwd)

find . -name SHA1SUMS | while read -r fname; do
    cd "$here" || exit
    dirn=$(dirname "$fname")
    cd "$dirn" || continue
    sha1sum --quiet --check SHA1SUMS 2>&1 | grep " FAILED" | ( echo -n "$dirn/"; cat )
done > logfile
```

This will break if you have directories containing `\n` but it would be extremely unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -name SHA1SUMS -execdir \
  sh -c 'sha1sum --quiet -c "$@" | sed "s|^|$PWD/|"' - {} +
```

If the directories really contain `|`, you can use some other character in the sed substitution, or use `awk -v p="$PWD/" "{print p\$0}"` instead.

If your paths really contain *newlines* you need something smarter than this ;-)